# How to insert a html special character in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, unicode, jtextpane

I have read many threads on JTextPane and it made me start writing a little text editor using JTextPane, but in the middle  of the project am almost folding up! Please can some one explain to me how i can insert an html character int a textpane like

```
JTextPane pane = new JtextPane(); 
pane.settext("&cent;");
```

My problem is that if i have already keyed in some text and I then use the `settext` mathod to insert a special character on the same line of text then the special character is inserted while the previous text disappears. How can I stop that happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902529/jtextpane-jtextfield-strange-behaviour-with-rare-characters

Comment: Read here [setting JTextPane to content type HTML and using string builders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071389/setting-jtextpane-to-content-type-html-and-using-string-builders)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said when you want to call `setText`. If you want to do it in response to a button click, then you just need to:

1. Read the text from the (captured variable for the) pane
2. Append your desired character
3. (Optionally) use `grabFocus` to put the focus and input caret back into the text pane.

The code would look like this:

```java
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("add");
jPanel1.add(btnAdd);
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String text = pane.getText();
        pane.setText(text + "¢");
        pane.grabFocus();
    }               
});
```

If you are working with HTMLDocument (you haven't posted your full code, so it is not clear what you are doing to produce HTML), you could do something like:

```java
pane = new JTextPane();
jPanel1.add(pane);
final HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
final HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();
pane.setEditorKit(kit);
pane.setDocument(doc);  
...    
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int start = pane.getSelectionStart();
        try {
            //  add a span containing the desired element inside the current paragraph or other containing element
            kit.insertHTML(doc, start, "<span>&cent;</span>", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.SPAN);
        } catch ...
        pane.grabFocus();
    }               
});
```